# Can't get better OCR recognition quality with Tesseract in Java for specific samples

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

Dear StackOverflowers,

I am currently working on a Java program utilizing bytedecos Tesseract port (https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/tesseract) to extract text from a very specific kind of images. All images contain 5x5 to 7x7 matrices with each matrix element consisting of a hex number.

The example image I currently try to extract from is this one:
[image: first image of matrix]

With some preprocessing and binarization, converted to png:
[image]

Original image size is 395x395, size of preprocessed image is 790x790.

For this image, Tesseract gives me the following result (with page segmentation mode 6 automatically chosen by Tesseract itself):

```
1C 55 E9 55 E9
E9 18 18 BD 18
55 E9 18 E9 55
E9 18 55 55 BD
E9 10 BD 55 55
```

My testcode for text extraction (ignore the `return null` at the end, will be replaced by a proper return value later):

```
private String[] analyseStep(String imagePath) {
        BytePointer outText;

        TessBaseAPI api = new TessBaseAPI();
        if(api.Init(null, "eng") != 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Tesseract!");
        }

        System.out.println("Analyzing: " + imagePath);

        PIX image = pixRead(imagePath);
        api.SetImage(image);
        outText = api.GetUTF8Text();

        System.out.println("OCR result:\n" + outText.getString());

        return null;
    }
```

As you can see, recognition is already good, but it seems to have severe problems with the letter "C" nonetheless, sometimes correctly recognizing it as "C", sometimes as "8", sometimes as "0". This is a big problem, since i have to automatically process the images later, extract the correct text and then perform operations on it, so ideally there are no recognition errors whatsoever.

I already tried the following operations on the image to improve recognition, all with no improvements as of yet:

- Converting the image from .jpg to .png and .tif
- Color inversion
- Contrast enhancement
- Erosion and Dilation
- Doubling image size from 395x395 to 790x790
- Trying all page segmentation modes of Tesseract (mode 6 "Assume a single uniform block of text." gives the result above, which is the already the best of all results)
- Splitting the matrix in five rows

I would greatly appreciate any hint or advice on what else i could try to correctly recognize all letters in the image.

**Addendum, maybe unrelated to recognition quality:**
Also, after each run of Tesseract, i get the following error messages at the end, i don't know if they have anything to do with the bad recognition quality:

```
Warning: Parameter not found: enable_new_segsearch
ObjectCache(00007ffcf9d5a4e0)::~ObjectCache(): WARNING! LEAK! object 00000209807427e0 still has count 1 (id D:\[some folders omitted]\src\main\resources\tessdata/eng.traineddatapunc-dawg)
ObjectCache(00007ffcf9d5a4e0)::~ObjectCache(): WARNING! LEAK! object 0000020980742770 still has count 1 (id D:\[some folders omitted]\src\main\resources\tessdata/eng.traineddataword-dawg)
ObjectCache(00007ffcf9d5a4e0)::~ObjectCache(): WARNING! LEAK! object 0000020980742a80 still has count 1 (id D:\[some folders omitted]\src\main\resources\tessdata/eng.traineddatanumber-dawg)
ObjectCache(00007ffcf9d5a4e0)::~ObjectCache(): WARNING! LEAK! object 0000020980742380 still has count 1 (id D:\[some folders omitted]\src\main\resources\tessdata/eng.traineddatabigram-dawg)
ObjectCache(00007ffcf9d5a4e0)::~ObjectCache(): WARNING! LEAK! object 0000020980742850 still has count 1 (id D:\[some folders omitted]\src\main\resources\tessdata/eng.traineddatafreq-dawg)
```

(I am using Tesseract with Maven in IntelliJ. Dependency from pom.xml if this helps:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>tesseract-platform</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1-1.5.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Content of tessdata, which i had to download manually:
[image]
)

Comment: [What The Font](https://www.myfonts.com/pages/whatthefont) says this is [Bourgeois Rounded Medium](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/bourgeois-rounded-font-virus).  Can you train Tesseract on that specific font?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Probably, but I am totally new to Tesseract and training it on a specific font seems pretty involved to me at this point. I would rather like to find an "easier" solution, if possible, using training only as a very last resort :)

Comment: If your goal is accuracy, training Tesseract on that specific font is your best strategy.